# Erlang Compilation Error : Undefined function

Tags: erlang, syntax-error, undefined, erlang-otp

I haven't been doing Erlang for a while so I am practicing but I don't get it anymore :(

```
-module(conversion).
-export([convert/1, convertMeteoCelcius/1]).

convert({celcius, Degres}) -> {farenheit, (Degres * 1.8) + 32};
convert({celcius, Degres}) -> {celcius, Degres};
convert({farenheit, Degres}) -> {celcius, (Degres - 32)/1.8};
convert({farenheit, Degres}) -> {farenheit, Degres}.

convertMeteoCelcius([], [Result])
    -> [Result];

convertMeteoCelcius([{City, {Unit, Temp}}|Rest], [Result]) 
    -> convertMeteoCelcius([Rest], [{City, convert({celcius, Temp})}, Result]).

convertMeteoCelcius([Raw]) -> formatMeteoCelcius([Raw], []).
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one compiler error: undefined `formatMeteoCelcius/2` in the last line.  I suppose that you meant `convertMeteoCelcius`.  Changing that, your code compiles.

On the other hand, you then get three warning messages.  The third one is about the unused `Unit` variable, and I suppose you can safely ignore it.  The other two, however, show two potential problems in your code:

```
conversion.erl:5: Warning: this clause cannot match
                  because a previous clause at line 4 always matches
conversion.erl:7: Warning: this clause cannot match
                  because a previous clause at line 6 always matches
```

The first warning basically says that you will have to decide what you want the result of `convert({celcius, 0})` to be.  It cannot be both `{farenheit, 32}` and `{celcius, 0}`.

You may have been mislead by the apparent similarity between Erlang and Prolog.  Erlang is not a logic programming language; it is functional.  For every function defined using pattern matching, one pattern will be used deterministically every time you call it.